# Description and default value not appearing in Storybook when rendering React/Mui components

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm using `Storybook` v6.5.9 to render out my React/MUI components. Everything works fine, but I can't get the description or default value to appear in the canvas under the Controls tab:

[image: Description and default not appearing]

The description appears fine when looking at the Docs tab:

[image: Description and default appear]

There's nothing in the default export and I haven't changed any default options out of the box.

Answer (score 7):

According to the **React Storybook** docs under controls [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls)

Under the directory of **.storybook/preview.js**

We need to add the following under **controls** key

```
export const parameters = {
  .....
  controls: {
    expanded: true
  }
  .....
}
```

This ensures that each control is viewed in expanded mode globally **(both in Canvas and Docs tabs)**